# Unique computer ID

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to get unique computer ID.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101772/win32-processoris-processorid-unique-for-all-computers) I can't use processor ID for this purpose. Can I take motherboard ID? What is the best way to identify the computer?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: One would assume (rash, I appreciate, when answering programming questions) that once a generic mechanism has been identified a specific implementation in C# will be desired...

Comment: What tag should I use for this question?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443093/what-is-a-good-unique-pc-identifier/3443148#3443148

Comment: you should tag it with C# if you want an example of how to get a unique computer ID in C#... which I'm guessing is what you're after isn't it?

Comment: @djdd87: The asker *did* use the [tag:c#] tag, some other user who didn't read the tag wiki incorrectly applied [tag:system-identification] in its place.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like you've said CPU Id wont be unique, however you can use it with another hardware identifier to create your own unique key.

Reference assembly `System.Management`

So, use this code to get the CPU ID:

```
string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
     cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
     break;
}
```

Then use this code to get the HD ID:

```
string drive = "C";
ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(
    @"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + @":""");
dsk.Get();
string volumeSerial = dsk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
```

Then, you can just combine these two serials to get a uniqueId for that machine:

```
string uniqueId = cpuInfo + volumeSerial;
```

Obviously, the more hardware components you get the IDs of, the greater the uniqueness becomes. However, the chances of the same machine having an identical CPU serial and Hard disk serial are already slim to none.

Comment: As I said before processor ID is not appropriate.

Comment: I see your point. I just doubt what will I get if there's a RAID and there are 2 different HDD with disk C on them.

Comment: @StuffHappens - I'm assuming it'll probably end up returning the RAID controller ID or something. I'm sure Microsoft has considered that.

Comment: @StuffHappens, just hash together multiple IDs of hard disks.

Comment: FWIW, I built a unique id generator using processor id and disk serial number (with fallbacks), and it failed on a pair of machines we'd purchased from Dell at the same time.

Comment: I need to use something like this from within an application that's published via ClickOnce.  My end users may have rather restricted access to their PCs.  Will this method cause any problems if the end-user is not an Admin on their machine?  Will this work with XP/7/8?  Thank you.  I really need to derive a unique, local key for my project.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea I am getting an error : Attempt by security transparent method 'demo.Program.demo()' to access security critical method 'System.Management.ManagementClass..ctor(System.String)' failed.

Comment: This does not produce a unique ID. We so far tested this on 15 machines purchased from Dell and already have 3 with the same ID.

Comment: Maybe try more than just the two components like the answer says?

Answer (score 5):

MAC address of the network adapter?
Security identifier (SID) of the windows OS install? (assuming it's windows you're dealing with)
Could you just generate a GUID for each PC?

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If he's trying to do this for a licencing mechanism, then SIDs and MAC addresses can be changed very easily so wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

The motherboard ID is a pretty unique identifier. Another option is to use the network cards MAC address, which are pretty much unique.

Comment: Should be noted however that MACs can be changed from the NIC properties window for a lot of NICs, while a motherboard ID is a lot harder to change.

Comment: As far as I know you can change your mac address. And what to do if there are more than one netboard (or how should I name it)?

Comment: That is correct. A motherboard ID is far more unique. However, if you do not require very strong uniqueness (i.e you can assume MACs don't change), acquiring a mac address is far easier.

@Stuff, hash the addresses together? :)