# How can I obtain a unique machine fingerprint in a reliable way?

Tags: c#, security, hardware, guid, uniqueidentifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique computer id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474940/unique-computer-id)

I'm developing a server/client application which needs to implement a string client tracking system for different purposes (licences, security, etc...) assigning to every new registered client a unique identity. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CodeProject article that covers this reasonably well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer

Comment: This code have an problem! In some cases the fingerprint produced is different, without any hardware change.

Comment: @ECC and did you find a solution or change anything?

Comment: @juFo, in my case I simplified my approach. What I really needed was simpler and only with the HD serial number, solved for me.