# get unique value from Linux OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, operating-system

I'm trying to get unique value from Linux server, something like hardware id, for non-root user
I tried to use the mac address of the network interface but in the venet0 interface (virtual network interface) there is no mac address
and the output of the `ip addr` command is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
    inet x.x.x.x/32 brd x.x.x.x scope global venet0:0
    inet6 ::2/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft foreve
```

so what is the best way to do that for non-root user and by using build in Linux command that's work on all Linux distributions?

Comment: There may not be a unique hardware ID if you're using a virtual environment.

Comment: [Is there a UUID type of value in Linux that can uniquely identify an instance of a VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8722050/608639), [Best way to get machine id on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10152762/608639), [Generate consistent machine unique ID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144812), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the [CPU ID, or better the general computer UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22991546/5794048):

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep UUID
```

See the linked thread for more options. As you seem to work in a virtualized environment, check that they are actually unique. Perhaps also incorporate the hostname.

Comment: this required root privilege, but I ask for non-root privilege user