# How to get motherboard address or processor id / serial number in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

I need to fetch the serial number of the motherboard or processor in a C/C++ program.

I need to identify a unique computer for my software so that one license can not be used in multiple computers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90462/cpu-serial-number

Comment: Which operating system ?

Answer (score 0):

HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) can give the motherboard serial number on Linux.
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal

This is the library behind `lshal`:

```
$ lshal | grep 'system\.hardware\.serial'
  system.hardware.serial = '<serial-number>'
```